# Java EE standard for logging in session for mobiles?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, backend

Is there any standard for backend developers to write login module if the clients are mobile applications? The best would be implementation independant.

For now I'm using old security-realms declarative mechanism for JBoss only and I wish to have newer one.

I was reading about JEE8's Security API, but there is nothing useful for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific standard for logging in with mobile application, part of the point of Java/Jakarta EE is that it is client-agnostic, it is irrelevant what people are trying to login from.

In terms of APIs to use, for security what is now recommended is the EE 8 [Security API](https://javaee.github.io/security-spec/), which is comprehensive but suffers from a lack of documentation. The other API you may want to look at is [Microprofile JWT](https://microprofile.io/project/eclipse/microprofile-jwt-auth) for sending messages post-authorisation.